# How to make a sprite which has physicsBody unmovable/static upon collision?

Tags: ipad, ios8, sprite-kit, collision-detection

I have a game with balloons. I am adding the balloons from the bottom and they fly up while able to fly offscreen. I gave the balloons physicsBodys so they collide which each other but I want to make the balloons bouce of the left and right edge of the screen. I found a solution where the sprite object bounce of all screens on Rays site. But I need a different solution. 
This is my balloon code:

```
MBDBallon *randomBallon = [[MBDBallon alloc] initWithImageName:balloonImageName
                                               andBallonSize:ballonSize
                                               withBallonImageName:[self.balloonColorImageNamesArray objectAtIndex:balloonWithColorIndex]
                                               withStartingPosition:CGPointMake(self.viewSize.width/2, - self.viewSize.height )];

                    //randomBallon.name = [self returnRandomImageNameFromArray:self.ballonSpriteImageNamesArray];
                randomBallon.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
                randomBallon.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = balloonCategory;
                randomBallon.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = balloonCategory;
                randomBallon.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = balloonCategory;
```

and this is my left wall code:

```
  SKSpriteNode *leftWall = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithColor:[UIColor redColor] size:CGSizeMake( self.viewSize.width / 15, self.viewSize.height * 3 )];
    [leftWall setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f)];

    leftWall.position = CGPointMake( self.viewSize.width / 15 , 0.0f );
    leftWall.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake( self.viewSize.width / 15, self.viewSize.height * 3 )];
    leftWall.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = balloonCategory;
    leftWall.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = balloonCategory;
    leftWall.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = balloonCategory;
    leftWall.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
    leftWall.physicsBody.allowsRotation     = NO;
    leftWall.physicsBody.dynamic            = NO;
    leftWall.physicsBody.friction = 0.0f;
    [self addChild:leftWall];
```

However the walls is moving after some few balloon collisions. I really don't know wheres the catch or property to stop such behavior. The :

```
leftWall.physicsBody.dynamic            = NO;
```

Should stop all movement but it doesn't. Please help, thanks :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not properly set up your categoryBitMasks.

```
randomBallon.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = balloonCategory;
randomBallon.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = wallCategory|balloonCategory;

leftWall.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = wallCategory;
leftWall.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = balloonCategory;
```

CategoryBitMask is the category you  want to assign to your sprite.  CollisionBitMask is the category you want your sprite to collide with.  Balloons in this case should be set to collide with walls and other balloons.  Walls should be set to only collide with balloons.

Comment: Works on iOS 8.1 (device) and iOS 8.1,7.1 simulator. Nice and simple explanation. Ty :)